# I hide HLS URL using PHP to output files but doesn't work

Tags: php, .htaccess, m3u8

This is my original URL: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/01/MV01/index.m3u8
For security concern I moved all HLS files outside the document root of web site (/var/www/html).
IE. move them to /var/www/video/01/MV01/index.m3u8 including all .ts files in the same folder.

And then I created a .htaccess in the document root:

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*ts$|.*m3u8$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) auth.php?file=$1 [NC,L]
```

This will redirect all requirement and get files outputted by php.

auth.php:

```
//
Some codes to check authorization first.
//
$reqpath = strip_tags($_GET['file']);
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache,must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0",false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header('Content-type:application/force-download');
if (strpos($_GET['file'],".ts")>1) header("Content-type: video/MP2T");
if (strpos($_GET['file'],".m3u8")>1) header("Content-type: application/x-mpegURL");
@readfile("/var/www/video/".$reqpath);
```

My purpose is when user accesses http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/01/MV01/index.m3u8 he still can play the video.

The result is:
It is working well on iOS and Android but can not play on PC including jwplayer and VLC.

The error message on jwplayer is " Error loading player: No playable sources found"
The error message on VLC is "main input error: no suitable demux module for 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/01/MV01/index.m3u8'

**I use the HLS sample files download on apple.com so I think the .m3u8 and .ts files are no problem.

Help!

Comment: auth.php?file=../../../etc/passwd

Comment: Sure, I have prevented this and will do more restrictions. Thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved it finally.

Why can only play on iOS and Android but not on PC? I guess the problem should be in the outputting in PHP so I tried to change the HTTP header and then I found the answer.

Just add one more header:

```
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize("/var/www/video/".$reqpath));
```

All of the header here

```
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache,must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0",false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header('Content-type:application/force-download');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($filename));
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize("/var/www/video/".$reqpath));
header('Content-Type: '.mime_content_type("/var/www/video/".$reqpath));
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am not sure if you are still around but this is exactly what I needed and saved me a lot of time.